# Sonarqube in Docker Compose request error 400 using container name

Tags: docker-compose, sonarqube

I have a deploy in Docker Compose using a custom network with Jenkins, Sonarqube and Posgresql. I can ping sonarqube using its name:

```
$ping sonarqube
PING sonarqube (172.22.0.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.6: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
```

`Resolve to IP 172.22.0.6`

When I use its name in url `http://sonarqube:9000` I get 400 Bad Request.

```
$curl http://sonarqube:9000
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1></body></html>
```

But if I use IP address, it works!

```
$curl http://172.22.0.6:9000

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="application-name" content="SonarQube" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-512x512.png" />
    <title>SonarQube</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/outV7HKTALN.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="global-loading">
            <i class="spinner global-loading-spinner"></i> 
            <span class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.baseUrl = '';
        window.serverStatus = 'UP';
        window.instance = 'SonarQube';
        window.official = true;
    </script>

    <script type="module" src="/js/outZA7ASMV3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to do a configuration in SonarQube or user a proxy? I want to use its name because containers are created and destroyed, Thanks

**EDIT** Docker Compose File

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  gitlab_promad:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: 'gitlab_promad'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - promad_devsecops
      
  mobsf_promad:
    image: 'opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest'
    container_name: 'mobsf_promad'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - promad_devsecops

  jenkins_promad:
    image: 'test:v3'
    container_name: 'jenkins_promad'
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home'
    networks:
      - promad_devsecops
  
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    container_name: 'sonarqube'
    depends_on:
      - db_promad
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db_promad:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - /srv/sonarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - /srv/sonarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - /srv/sonarqube/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    networks:
      - promad_devsecops

  db_promad:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: 'db_promad'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - /srv/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - /srv/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - promad_devsecops

networks:
  promad_devsecops:
    name: 'promad_devsecops'
```

Comment: Can you provide the docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Yes, I edited question